# How to handle json that returns both a string and a string array?

Tags: c#, json

I'm using the Yahoo fantasy sports api. I'm getting a result like this:

```
"player": [
    {
        ...
        "eligible_positions": {
            "position": "QB"
        },
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "eligible_positions": {
            "position": [
                "WR",
                "W/R/T"
            ]
        },
        ...
    },
```

How is it that I can deserialize this?

My code looks like this:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

if (response != null)
{
    JSONResponse JSONResponseObject = json.Deserialize<JSONResponse>(response);
    return JSONResponseObject;
}
```

And in my JSONResponse.cs file:

```
public class Player
{
    public string player_key { get; set; }
    public string player_id { get; set; }
    public string display_position { get; set; }        
    public SelectedPosition selected_position { get; set; }
    public Eligible_Positions eligible_positions { get; set; }
    public Name name { get; set; }            
}


public class Eligible_Positions
{        
    public string position { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this, since eligible_positions can return both a string and a string array, I keep getting the error "Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array".

I've also tried turning `public string position { get; set; }` to `public string[] position { get; set; }` but I still get an error.

How should I handle this?

Comment: What is the error when you use `string[]`? Have you tried `List<string>` ?

Comment: @IainBallard: That won't help.

Comment: Yes. When I use string[], I get "System.String' to type 'System.String[]". When I use List<string>, I get "Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'";

Comment: I think this one may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141610/in-c-sharp-how-can-i-deserialize-this-json-when-one-field-might-be-a-string-or-a

Comment: @user850237 Are you open to use Json.Net?

Comment: I'm open to anything as long as it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/). The idea is: *"declare `position` as a `List<string>` and if the value in json is a string. then convert it to a List"*

**Code to deserialize**

```
var api = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SportsAPI>(json);
```

**JsonConverter**

```
public class StringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {

        if(reader.ValueType==typeof(string))
        {
            return new List<string>() { (string)reader.Value };
        }
        return serializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Sample Json**

```
{
    "player": [
        {
            "eligible_positions": {
                "position": "QB"
            }
        },
        {
            "eligible_positions": {
                "position": [
                    "WR",
                    "W/R/T"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Classes (Simplified version)**

```
public class EligiblePositions
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringConverter))] // <-- See This
    public List<string> position { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public EligiblePositions eligible_positions { get; set; }
}

public class SportsAPI
{
    public List<Player> player { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This was nice and easy and works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Hey L.B

Can you help me out with this .
The reader.value is null and I m looking at List<Class> rather than List<string>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486801/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-name-value-when-length-o/31486836

Comment: Is it best to add `CanWrite` if you don't implement `WriteJson`

`public override bool CanWrite
{
    get { return false; }
}`