# JSON .NET deserialize string[] instead of string

Tags: c#, json

I have an inconsistent JSON file, that was likely generated by hand.  Here's a truncated example:

```
[
    {
        "Generic Name": "Lurasidone",
        "Brand Name": ["Latuda"]
    }
    {
        "Generic Name": "Lisdexamfetamine",
        "Brand Name": "Vyvanse"
    }
]
```

Since "Brand Name" is [] for one, and just a regular string for another, how do I take care of this in .NET?

```
public class Drug
{
    [JsonProperty("Generic Name")]
    public string GenericName {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("Brand Name")]
    public string[] BrandName {get; set;}
}

List<Drug> a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Drug>>(
    File.ReadAllText("d.json"));
```

Results in the error:

> Error converting value "Vyvanse" to type 'System.String[]'. Path '[1].Brand Name', line 20, position 26.

Comment: You'll have to use a [custom converter](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) and perhaps use a try-catch to parse it one way and if it fails, parse it the other way. The exact implementation can go different routes. Nasty JSON creates nasty code.

Comment: The `BrandName` on the second object is not a `array`.

Comment: @FelipeOriani that was the question

Comment: the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052430/how-to-handle-json-that-returns-both-a-string-and-a-string-array answered my question