# How to deserialize JSON string into a C# object?

Tags: c#, json

Consider the following: You have a service which returns a JSON string, and in your C# code you would like to use the returned value as an object (e.g.: get the various properties of it by their names).

Sample JSON:

```
{ 
    "Name": "Jon Smith", 
    "Address": 
    { 
        "City": "New York",
        "State": "NY" 
    },
    "Age": 42 
}
```

Sample C# usage:

```
var object = ... // this is what I am asking for
Console.WriteLine(object.Name); // this should print out "Jon Smith"
Console.WriteLine(object.Address.State); // this should print out "NY"
```

What options are available in C# **without** using third party libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know the exact data contract (or you don't care about it), then you can easily do that with the help of [`System.Web.Helpers.Json`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx) class and a [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) object:

```
dynamic json = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(@"{ ""Name"": ""Jon Smith"", ""Address"": { ""City"": ""New York"", ""State"": ""NY"" }, ""Age"": 42 }");
Console.WriteLine(json.Name);           // prints "Jon Smith"
Console.WriteLine(json.Address.State);  // prints "NY"
```

A note on that: you will have to add reference to the `System.Web.Helpers` assembly.

Of course not everyone likes `dynamic`, there are some people who prefer to have well defined data contracts. For them the solution is a little bit longer:

You have to create matching classes for your data contracts, and [attribute them accordingly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
// class for the root object:
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

// class for the address object:
[DataContract]
public class Address
{
    [DataMember]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

You can mark members with [`IgnoreDataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to, well, ignore them, or add [`IsRequired=true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.isrequired(v=vs.110).aspx) to make them mandatory.

After defining those contracts, you can easily parse the JSON string into a `Person` object:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
using( MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"{ ""Name"": ""Jon Smith"", ""Address"": { ""City"": ""New York"", ""State"": ""NY"" }, ""Age"": 42 }")))
{
    var person = (Person)ser.ReadObject(stream);
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);             // prints "Jon Smith"
    Console.WriteLine(person.Address.State);    // prints "NY"
}
```

Note: the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.90).aspx) resides in the `System.ServiceModel.Web` assembly, so you will have to add a reference for that. (And of course for the `System.Runtime.Serialization` assembly as well.)

To make it easier to use, you can add static `Parse` and `TryParse` methods to your data contract class:

```
public static Person Parse(string jsonString)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonString)) throw new ArgumentNullException("The jsonString parameter shouldn't be null or an empty string.");

    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)))
    {
        return (Person)ser.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}

public static bool TryParse(string jsonString, out Person result)
{
    try
    {
        result = Person.Parse(jsonString);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is ArgumentNullException || ex is SerializationException)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

---

As L.B. mentioned in their comment, you can use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) - if you add a reference to the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly - to make it even simpler:

```
var person = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person>(@"{ ""Name"": ""Jon Smith"", ""Address"": { ""City"": ""New York"", ""State"": ""NY"" }, ""Age"": 42 }");
```

For that you still need the classes from above, but you can leave out the - "ugly" - attributes if you would like to. (But with this method you lose the ability to mark parts as mandatory...)

Comment: Were you supposed to answer this under a different account? All looks a bit odd at the moment what with question and (very long) answer being within 1 minute of each other by the same user.

Comment: There is an option here to answer your own question... They get posted at the same time. I find it a quite good way to document problems you face, and have a way to find them later.

Comment: @qqbenq If you used `JavaScriptSerializer`, you wouldn't need those ugly attributes. A one line deserialization is also possible. `new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person>(jsonstring)`

Comment: @L.B Thanks, I incorporated that in my answer, but that method also has some drawbacks: you lose the ability to mark fields as mandatory, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @qqbenq What do you mean by mandatory, if that field doesn't exist in json, you'll get the default value. BTW: You can use `ScriptIgnore` attribute if needed.

Comment: @qqbenq BTW: I am fan of Json.Net, which has the most control over serialization/deserialization process. No need for other ones.... See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052430/how-to-handle-json-that-returns-both-a-string-and-a-string-array/22053420#22053420)

Comment: @L.B By mandatory I mean that a field must be present in the json string, otherwise the parsing should fail. Is there a way to achieve that with JavaScriptSerializer? And yes, I agree that Json.Net is great, but now my question was specific about not using third party libraries :)