# JSON Serialization in WPF Browser Application

Tags: c#, json, wpf, serialization

I was wondering how to serialize and de-serialize json Content in a wpf browser application.
I tried System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, but this library is not available, like System.Web.Script.Serialization ... And I can't found any other way with Google, does anyone of you know something or have an idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508255/how-to-deserialize-json-string-into-a-c-sharp-object) question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to qqbenq, I found the following library:

http://james.newtonking.com/json

This works very well!