# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) when length of the list is only

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I get cannot deserialize error when the items in the json list is 1 , it works when the items are > 1

This is my json

```
  {
   "avetmiss": {

  "disabilities": {
    "disability": [
      {
        "disability-type": "Physical"
      },
      {
        "disability-type": "Hearing/Deaf"
      }
    ]
  },
  "prior-educations": {
    "prior-education": {
      "id": "2",
      "prior-education-type": "Bachelor Degree or Higher Degree level"
    }
  }
}}
```

and this is the class with which I deserialize

```
 public class Root {
     public PriorEducations prioreducations { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("disabilities")]
    public Disabilities disabilities { get; set; }
}

public class Disabilities
{
    [JsonProperty("disability")]
    public List<DisabilityType> disability { get; set; }
}

public class DisabilityType
{
    [JsonProperty("disability-type")]
    public string disabilitytype { get; set; }
}

public class PriorEducations
{
    [JsonProperty("prior-education")]
    public List<PriorEducation> prioreducation { get; set; }
}

public class PriorEducation
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("prior-education-type")]
    public string prioreducationtype { get; set; }
}
```

So basically it works with Disabilities but not with prior education (because the items in Disabilities are >1 where as prior edu.. is 1 )
It works if I change the prioreducation[] to prioreducation

Comment: Show the json for  `list is 1` case . I guess it is not an array `[]` but an object `{}`

Comment: Hey EZI
Can you give me a sample please .

Comment: Refresh this page and see the answer marked as duplicate.. Keyword is: *writing a custom JsonConverter*

Comment: Hey EZI ,
tried the solution from L.B but I get the reader.value as null .

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n which may be a better match for this question.

Comment: Thanks dbc , I found that solution to be the perfect one as it uses a templated type and works with any object.