# How to deserialize a JSON object containing an object or object array

Tags: c#, json, whois

I'm trying to deserialize the JSON response that I get back from the ARIN whois REST API.  I'm new to JSON but I *think* they are returning two different schemas depending on the results and I'm having a hard time taking it apart.

Here is an abridged version of the JSON that's returned if there are multiple **net** objects:

```
{
  "nets": {
    "@xmlns":{"ns3":"http:\/\/www.arin.net\/whoisrws\/netref\/v2",
    "net": [{
        "customerRef": {
          "@name": "Internet Customer",
        },
      }, {
        "orgRef": {
          "@name": "Internet Service Provider",
        },
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that **nets** is an array of **net** objects.  When there is only one **net** object returned, the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "nets": {
    "@xmlns":{"ns3":"http:\/\/www.arin.net\/whoisrws\/netref\/v2",
    "net": {
        "orgRef": {
          "@name": "Internet Customer",
        },
      }
  }
}
```

In this case **nets** is an object that contains a single **net** object. I can define my class with an array or with a single embedded object but deserializing with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ARINWhois>(response)` will throw an exception on results that don't agree with my schema.

I've considered two options:

1. Deserialize it all by hand with `JsonTextReader`.
2. Define both object schemas and retry with the other one if an exception is thrown.

Is there is an easier and more elegant solution?

Comment: Note that neither of your extracts are valid JSON on their own (the commas after the last elements are not allowed).

Comment: My bad.  The original JSON is quite long and my cut/paste foo was weak.

Comment: Would be helpful if you post your model also, such as `ARINWhois` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle json that returns both a string and a string array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052430/how-to-handle-json-that-returns-both-a-string-and-a-string-array)

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I think that might be my solution but I need to go off and study it a bit.  If that doesn't resolve it, I will post my model for `ARINWhois` and we can pick up where we left off.

Comment: That link wasn't exactly what I needed but it led to [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n which was.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Eser22 who pointed me toward the use of JsonConverter which does exactly what I need.  [How to Handle both a single item and an array for the same property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n) is an excellent explanation.  Works perfectly!

Here is the final version of my code.

```
/*
 * parse the response
 */
ARINWhois WhoisResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ARINWhois>(response);

/*
 *  custom converter
 */
class SingleOrArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
  {
    return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
  }

  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
    if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
      return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
    }
    return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
  }

  public override bool CanWrite
  {
    get { return false; }
  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}

/*
 * data models
 */
public class ARINWhois
{
  [JsonProperty("nets")]
  public ARINNets Network { get; set; }
}
public class ARINNets
{
  [JsonProperty("net")]
  [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<ARINNet>))]
  public List<ARINNet> Networks;
}

public class ARINNet
{
  [JsonProperty("registrationDate")]
  public ARINregistrationDate RegistrationDate;
  [JsonProperty("orgRef")]
  public ARINorgRef Organization;
  [JsonProperty("customerRef")]
  public ARINcustomerRef Customer;
}
public class ARINregistrationDate
{
  [JsonProperty("$")]
  public string date { get; set; } 
}
public class ARINorgRef
{
  [JsonProperty("@name")]
  public string name { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("@handle")]
  public string handle { get; set; }
}
public class ARINcustomerRef
{
  [JsonProperty("@name")]
  public string name { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("@handle")]
  public string handle { get; set; }
}
```