# C# Json serialize different types

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to retrieve all data from a JSON file to my C# application.
But now the problem is that the field "info" in my json file is sometimes from the type string but it can also be the type object.

```
{
    [
        {
            "id":"147786",
            "canUpdate":true,
            "canDelete":true,
            "canArchive":true,
            "hasChildren":false,
            "info": "Test"
        },
        {
            "id":"147786",
            "canUpdate":true,
            "canDelete":true,
            "canArchive":true,
            "hasChildren":false,
            "info": [{"id"="1","messages":"true"}]
        }
    ]
}
```

well my model you can see here below, when there are only strings in my json file i can retrieve the data without any exception but when there are also objects in the info field then i get the error can't convert the value.

Is there a way to fix this on an easy way?

```
   public string id { get; set; }

    public string canUpdate { get; set; }


    public string info { get; set; }
```

Comment: Maybe `public dynamic info { get; set; }`

Comment: Or [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997172/7444103) (*managed*).

Comment: Duplicate of the previous: [How to handle json that returns both a string and a string array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22053420/7444103), just simpler.

Comment: If the types are compatible, then the linked posts will do the trick, but a string and an array of objects are not compatible.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [TypeNameHandling setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm), however you don't have any `$type` in your objects.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei  It would work. The OP, of course, would need to change the return type after `if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)`. The linked answer converts it to a `List<T>` (strings, there). Here, you can return another object type, depending on the desired result. That answer, as it is, should work anyway, but it would probably return a `List<JToken>`. You could also parse it later. Or not parse it all, or convert it. Btw, this: `"info": [{"id"="1","messages":"true"}]` appears to be wrong.

Comment: @Jimi Yes if you use `List<JToken>` (or probably a `List<dynamic>`) then the types are compatible and the linked solution will work. But I think a `List<JToken>` will not be better than a dynamic object.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Yes, well, I mean it would work directly (with no other edits, I think) if you just change the type of `Info` to `object` or `List<object>` -- I didn't mean to say that an object type is better then using dynamic (btw, I didn't even notice before that you posted an answer). I mean that implementing a custom converter to return a concrete type (making the necessary modifications to the code shown in those answers) would be a good choice, IMO. It depends on what the OP is going to use this output for.

Comment: @Jimi I also prefer having specific types and I agree, a  custom `Converter` can  handle the case.

Answer (score 2):

As an option you can define the `info` as `dynamic`:

```
public dynamic info { get; set; }
```

**Example**

Consider the following json string:

```
string json = @"
[
    { 'P1': 'X', 'P2': 'Y' },
    { 'P1': 'X', 'P2': [ 
        {'P11':'XX', 'P22':'YY'}, 
        {'P11':'XX', 'P22':'YY'}] 
    }
]";
```

You can define such model to deserialize it:

```
public class C
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public dynamic P2 { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize it like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<C[]>(json);
```

**Note**

If the number of dynamic properties is too much then usually there is no point in creating the class and the following code will be enough:

```
var obj = (dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```